# Dynamic places NameTokens GWT-Platform

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-platform

Hi I was wondering if it would be possible with the GWTP, create Presenters who can answer many NameTokens.

For example, instead of accessing the page from a user through "`!#user;param=caarlos0`" I could directly access "`!#caarlos0`" or "`/caarlos0`".

This is possible?
If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not supported. But there's an issue about many-to-many relationship between tokens and presenters (see http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/issues/detail?id=78).

If that's not exactly what you're looking for I guess it is a good place to post your feature request.

Comment: okay man, thanks for the link. about the dynamic name tokens, actually i do a ugly workaround in revealErrorPlace... That almost work.. is just very, very, very ugly... haha

Comment: `revealErrorPlace` sounds exaaactly like the place to do that :)